# How do I use conditional formatting inside of a CSS style sheet?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am looking to use some conditional styling for IE 9 - but I want to have the conditions inside my main style sheet - not using a second style sheet or referencing it in the HTML page. At the moment, I am putting this code in the HTML page, which works because it overwrites the other styles in the main style sheet:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
}
nav .four a:hover{
    color:white;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

But I would like to have these conditions in the CSS sheet, so that its all located in one place and I don't have to repeat the code in every page. I would also rather avoid having a separate CSS just for IE 9 - I already have one for IE 7-8. I tried this in the style sheet:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>

nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
}
nav .four a:hover{
    color:white;
}
<![endif]-->
```

The above code is specific for my `nav bar` for IE 9 (its a fix for the `nav bar` because IE 9 doesn't support text-shadows).

Is there a way to do this in the CSS style sheet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conditional Comments *are* only for HTML, but you *can* take advantage of it in your CSS.  HTML5Boilerplate does this by adding a class to the html element (https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

This gives you a hook you can use for targeting IE only:

```
.lt-ie8 .my-style { color: red }
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked. Will def start using boilerplate more often for future projects!

Answer (score 0):

That's standardly impossible. Conditional blocks in IE can only be used in HTML web pages.

*However*, the browser vendors have always been funny with their css parsers, including Microsoft. So there is some number of what we call [css hacks](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks) which can be used to have some rules interpreted by some parsers but not by others.

Please not that it's something which should be avoided if possible : the stylesheet will not be w3c compliant anymore, and it is definitely not a 'clean' solution (more like the dirty legacy workarounds which were commons during IE6's dark reign).

Comment: Oops. Well, at least it's not like [this](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/17198/42524/) mislinking ! Thanks

Comment: Haha, yikes! I practically feel the awkwardness oozing from that bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the ways to do what your asking. Number 6 is prob what your after. Just change the 9 to 11. http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/target-ie.php